# Informix "A syntax error has occurred." when using subquery

Tags: sql, syntax-error, informix

The following two queries are valid:

```
SELECT SUM(actdtmahi+actdtmahd+actdtmahv) AS saldo
FROM actdt 
WHERE actdtcage=116437 AND actdtmrcb=0 AND actdtccic=55204
```

And

```
SELECT FIRST 1 acbccccic FROM acbcc 
WhERE (acbccscic=4 OR acbccscic=5) AND 
    acbccccic IN (SELECT acbcaccic FROM acbca WHERE acbcacage=116437)
ORDER BY acbccccic DESC
```

But, if I try to join them in one query I get "A syntax error has occurred"

```
SELECT SUM(actdtmahi+actdtmahd+actdtmahv) AS saldo
FROM actdt 
WHERE actdtcage=116437 AND actdtmrcb=0 AND 
    actdtccic IN (SELECT FIRST 1 acbccccic FROM acbcc 
        WHERE (acbccscic=4 OR acbccscic=5) AND 
        acbccccic IN (SELECT acbcaccic FROM acbca WHERE acbcacage=116437)
        ORDER BY acbccccic DESC)
```

why?

Comment: I don't think Informix allows `FIRST` in subqueries.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @GordonLinoff, this was just a newbie mistake, now that it is 2023, and I look back to this question I can assure that it was a rookie mistake, haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Informix allows `FIRST` in subqueries.  Try `MAX()` instead:

```
actdtccic IN (SELECT MAX(acbccccic)
              FROM acbcc 
              WHERE acbccscic IN (4, 5) AND 
                    acbccccic IN (SELECT acbcaccic FROM acbca WHERE acbcacage=116437)
             )
```

Also, you can use `=` rather than `IN`.

Comment: As you're probably aware, `FIRST` does not mean any determinate value (not minimum, or maximum, nor necessarily first entered, or most recently entered, or …).  Using IN avoids errors from 'sub-query did not return exactly one row.  Dropping the `FIRST 1` would probably do the job; using `DISTINCT` instead of `FIRST 1` would probably also work.  I suspect that some of the IN clauses could be replaced by regular inner joins, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler . . . There is an `ORDER BY` in the subquery with `FIRST`, assuming I'm not reading the query incorrectly.

Comment: You're not — I am (misreading the query).  And in that case, the MAX operation is correct given that the ORDER BY has DESC as part of it.

Comment: Thank you!, I merged everything using `INNER JOIN` and also I used the `MAX()` function

Comment: Now that it is 2023, and I'm looking back to this old question, I can say that I was clueless about SQL, what a rookie mistake. Thank you for your comments